# AngFire add field in createuser()

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

Is there a way to add the field displayName when I create the user?
For example I'm working on this :

```
Signup(email: string, password: string, displayName: string) {
    this.angFire.auth.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      displayName: displayName
    }).catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log(er.....
```

But I had an error on displayName:

```
Argument of type '{ email: string; password: string; displayName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EmailPasswordCredentials'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'displayName' does not exist in type 'EmailPasswordCredentials'.
```

I'm using Firebase in ionic 2, angular2. If I put only email and password it works.

**UPDATE**

Could this works? Inside Signup function, after create the user, write this ?

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        let user1 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
          user1.displayName = displayName;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('no user');
      }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Can't it's just in read mode

Comment: `if (user != null) {
          user1.displayName = displayName;
        }` the condition should be `user1!=null`